# react-codemirror beforeChange event

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, codemirror, react-codemirror

I am using [react-codemirror](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-codemirror) node module as follows:

```
<CodeMirror 
  className={className} 
  value={this.state.code} 
  onBeforeChange={this.onBeforeChange} 
  onChange={this.onChange} 
  options={options}
/>
```

The [`change`](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#event_change) event works fine, but I can't seem to hook up with the [`beforeChange`](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#event_beforeChange) event. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I have declared handlers in my class as follows:

```
onBeforeChange(change) {
  console.log('calling beforeChange');
}

onChange(newCode) {
  this.setState({
    code: newCode
  });
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Author of [react-codemirror2](https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2) here. I stumbled upon your question and wanted to follow up with a detailed answer as there are some breaking changes in [3.x](https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2#new-in-300). The component now ships with an `UnControlled` and `Controlled` variant based on different use cases. I see you are calling `setState` within the `onBeforeChange` callback. In your case, I'd suggest leveraging the controlled component as such...

```
import {Controlled as CodeMirror} from 'react-codemirror2'

<CodeMirror
  value={this.state.value}
  options={options}
  onBeforeChange={(editor, data, value) => {
    this.setState({value}); // must be managed here
  }}
  onChange={(editor, metadata, value) => {
    // final value, no need to setState here
  }}
/>
```

With the controlled variant, managing state is *required* on the `value` prop to see any changes.

Additionally, the `UnControlled` component also has an `onBeforeChange` callback as well, yet with different behavior as such...

```
import {UnControlled as CodeMirror} from 'react-codemirror2'

<CodeMirror
  value={value}
  options={options}
  onBeforeChange={(editor, data, value, next) => {
    // hook to do whatever
    next();
  }}
  onChange={(editor, metadata, value) => {
  }}
/>
```

Here however, `onChange` will be deferred until `next` is invoked if `onBeforeChange` is specified. If not, `onChange` will fire regardless. Important to note, though, with the `UnControlled` variant, the editor will always react to input changes - the difference will simply be if `onChange` is called or not.

These changes were inspired due to the needs of the community and I encourage you to [open an issue](https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2/issues) should anything not be working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out react-codemirror does NOT expose the `beforeChange` event.

However, [react-codemirror2](https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2) does. A switch of library fixed this for me!

My final callback code:

```
onBeforeChange(cm, change, callOnChange) {

  const options = Object.assign({}, DEFAULT_OPTIONS, this.props.options)

  if (options.singleLine) {
    var after = change.text.join('').replace(/\n/g, '')
    change.update(change.from, change.to, [after])
  }

  callOnChange()
}

onChange(cm, change, code) {

  this.setState({ code })

  if (this.props.onChange) {
    this.props.onChange(code)
  }
}
```